# Creating multiple ClickOnce deployments of a WPF windows application

Tags: wpf, clickonce, mage

We have a WPF application which is distributed through ClickOnce deployments.  We have around 400 different users (customers) using this application. The only thing that changes per customer is a Web Service Url which is present in the app.config of the application.

For each of these customers, changing the app.config and then signing the clickonce deployment using mage or mage UI is time consuming and error prone.

Are there any ways to do this in an automated manner, so that we can manage all of these customers and creating new signed deployments faster ?

**EDIT**: IF there is no straightforward way to manage this issue only at a deployment level, I am open to making application or first time flow changes.

Comment: would passing the url as args value be a valid approach for you?

Comment: I guess so, can you please elaborate on how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter or parameters to your ClickOnce installation URL [as described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx). The parameter value will only be present during the initial install or update, so you'll have to store the web service URL locally if you allow the application to be run from the start menu.

Comment: The article says "You can only pass information in a query string when your application is being launched using HTTP, instead of using a file share or the local file system.". I guess this will not work for an application that has been downloaded from an URL. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: That's right, you only get the query string when the application is launched from the URL. This can be problematic if you have prerequisites and need to launch the bootstrapper (setup.exe) instead of launching from the application manifest directly.

Comment: Though this wasnt a direct answer to my question/scenario, it helped nudge the "powers-that-be" towards this kind of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of placing a variable in your top level window, and when your customer logs in or launches for the first time, you ask them to select a variable (Area? Website? Company? etc) and this sets that variable, which you then store and recall everytime the program starts up.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar thought where the user would have to choose some such value and the app could then contact a master web service and get their own version of the specific web service URL and write it into the config file. I wanted to see if it was in anyway possible without having to touch the application code.